# Adding shiny navbar element which triggers JS when clicked

Tags: r, shiny

This navigation bar is what I want:

[image]

However, clicking `Test`, should **not** open a panel, but just run some JS code, in this case create an alert. `Test` should look like a standard navbar element. This is what I tried ...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "test", inverse = T,
              tabPanel("Simulate", "simulate panel"),
              tabPanel("Test", "test panel"), 

             #------ Add onclick action ------#
             tags$script("var a = $('.navbar-nav  li:nth-child(2) a');
               a.attr('data-toggle', 'noclass');
               a.click(function() {
                  alert('link clicked');
               });")
  )

server <- function(input, output) { 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and it basically works, but when looking at the `ui` output, an additional `<li>`element is appended, which does not need to be there.

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-9138-1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Simulate">Simulate</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-9138-2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Test">Test</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-9138-3" data-toggle="tab"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

#### My questions:

1. **How can I create a link in the navbar avoiding the extra `li` element.**
2. **Is there a better way to achieve this, i.e. without messing so much with the `li` attributes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the script in the header of the `navbarPage` and the extra `li` will not be created. You can add an `id` to the navbarPage and use that to reference the element in your script:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "test", id = "nbpID", inverse = T,
                 header = tags$script("var a = $('#nbpID a[data-value=\"Test\"]');
                             a.attr('data-toggle', 'noclass');
                             a.click(function() {
                             alert('link clicked');
                             });"),
                 tabPanel("Simulate", "simulate panel"),
                 tabPanel("Test", "test panel")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```